# Position of elements slightly different on different browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, height

On my site the height of my #header and #nav look different in chrome/safari to firefox, I have a reset css, and have been really trying to discover the reason for this tiny but very annoying discrepancy. Maybe I need someone's fresh eyes to help me see it.

http://kimcolemanprojects.com/index.html

Any ideas much appreciated.

angela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reset stylesheet should come before your main stylesheet.

Simply swap them around and see if that helps.

Comment: I set my reset css first which fixed it in chrome, then I put <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
in my head like Kris Hollenbeck above suggested and that fixed it in firefox, as he was correct in saying that firefox was not reading my media query. So thanks to both of you, my design looks identical in browsers. x

Answer (score 2):

Browsers add automatically margin and padding

try to add the following code to your css:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

add that for each `h` tag 
your website look great by the way ;)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be your media query. Chrome is loading the media query and FireFox is not. Try adding this to your head and see if it fixes the problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**I see this in Firefox**

```
#header {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 8px 20px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**And this in Chrome**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px)
#header {
position: fixed;
width: 50%;
margin: 8px 20px;
line-height: 24px;
}
```